# How to determine when the viewContext of an NSPersistentContainer has finished merging changes from another NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm using an `NSPersistentContainer` to manage my app's Core Data stack. As you know, it has a `viewContext` property which is tied to the main queue in the app's main UI thread. I use it for reading data in the database. For writing new data (done in a background `NSOperation`), I use a background context via `newBackgroundContext()`, and then `save()` the background context up to the persistent store.

Now, the documentation on `viewContext` says this:

> This context is configured to be generational and to automatically consume save notifications from other contexts.

There isn't any more information in the Apple docs about how it consumes the save notifications but I imagine that `NSPersistentContainer` internally does `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on the `viewContext`. I want to be notified of when the `viewContext` finishes merging so that I can fire a function in my view controllers to re-fetch the updated data and display it.

However, I'm not aware of how to do this. There is no such thing as an NSManagedObjectContext delegate. I also think that listening for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` isn't the way to go, since it's fired when a context saves, not when the `viewContext` *finishes merging* the changes from the save.

Comment: Maybe this changed, but the docs say the view context in non-generational by default.  (Swift 4)